# If I start a performance as part of the the Countercharm feature, are my actions restricted on my next turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, actions, bard

Bards gain the [Countercharm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#Countercharm-93) feature at 6th level (emphasis added):

> As an action, you can start a performance **that lasts until the end of your next turn**. During that time, you and any friendly creatures within 30 feet of you have advantage on saving throws against being frightened or charmed. A creature must be able to hear you to gain this benefit. The performance ends early if you are incapacitated or silenced or if you voluntarily end it (no action required).

If the performance has not ended (and I have not voluntarily ended it), am I able to take my movement, action, and bonus action on my next turn? Or do I lose some or all of them?

The performance lasts until the end of my next turn, but it doesn't state whether or not I am able to take other actions while keeping the performance up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, Countercharm doesn't require extra actions on the following turn.

The Countercharm feature requires one action to activate.  The effects of the feature (i.e., the performance and its benefits) last until the end of your next turn.

There are conditions that can cause the effect to end early, however the feature does not say that it requires additional actions on the following turn. Since this doesn't mention any changes to your turn or actions, you would defer to the default rules for [using actions on your turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn).

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move.

The performance involved in Countercharm could reasonably be categorized this way, so it would not restrict the bard from speaking or performing verbal components for spells.  As long as the bard is not incapacitated or [silenced](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence), they are able to sustain the effect without spending additional actions.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I wasn't aware of that text about flourishes

Answer (score 0):

#### Probably not.

The rest of the [countercharm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#ClassFeatures)'s description tells us what it takes to perform:

> you gain the ability to use musical notes or **words of power** to disrupt mind-influencing effects.

Your performance consists of *words*, and singing does not prevent or disrupt any of your normal actions, except for possibly using the verbal components of spells.

Based on this, I would rule that you may maintain your performance as long as your performance is not interrupted by anything that restricts your voice or uses your voice for another purpose, such as casting a spell with verbal components.